# Calling a PHP function in a different file.

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'd like to call a php function from jQuery and return the value. I've previously done this with a ajax call to get a php file, but how do I call a specific php function in a php file? I have previously done this like ...

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "getBookedAppointmentDetails.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function (response){
                appHover.attr('title', response);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Just include the file, and use the function. (?)

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly call a php function on the webserver from a client script.

However, you can implement logic in the php script which parse/inspect the incoming request and then invoke a specific function.  That is assuming you have control of the php end.

Basically a REST api is what you should be aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create some conditional logic on `getBookedAppointmentDetails.php`, `if, switch, etc..` for example:

```
<?php
if($_GET['data']===1){
  first_function();
} elseif($_GET['data']===5) {
  other_function();
} else {
  (new my_class())->my_public_function();
}
exit(); //The page is done..
```

Or this:

```
$_GET['data']===1 ? first_function() : $_GET['data']===5 ? other_function() : (new my_class())->my_public_function();
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Ajax call is standard but there is a way to call php method inside a php file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function js_fun()
    {
        var x="<?php php_fun(); ?>";
        alert(x);
    }
</script>

<?php
    function php_fun()
    {
        require_once('target_file_with_proper_location.php');

        $value_from_far_away = somewhere_deep_inside_target_file();
        $value_from_far_away;
    }
?>
```